How to I type in contentEditable elements from a Chrome extension
What I want to do is:
I want to build a chrome extension or script that runs in the browser console that take a piece of text that I pass and then write it in whatever selector that I give.
The selector may be of contentEditable divs or input or textarea.
inputs and textarea work with the approach where i dispatch a keydown event with a specific character and then keyup and then change.
TL;DR input and textarea are not the problem
The main problem is contentEditable divs or spans . When ever I dipatch the above mentioned events nothing happens.
For test purpose lets take the x.com (previously twitter.com) 's post section with placeholder "What is happening ?"
When ever i dispatch events it does not register. I can click and then focus on it but nothing works

import { sleep } from "../utils"

export async function typeText(
  tabId: number,
  text: string,
  typingSpeed: number = 10
) {
  for (const char of text) {
    await chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId }, "Input.dispatchKeyEvent", {
      type: "keyDown",
      text: char
    })
    await sleep(typingSpeed)
    await chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId }, "Input.dispatchKeyEvent", {
      type: "keyUp",
      text: char
    })
    await sleep(typingSpeed)
  }
}

// I focus on the element where i want to type using element.focus() or element.click()
// And then run this function

// PS this code if from my chrome extension. 


This is my current code that works even in this kind of situation but it uses chrome debugger
which is not ideal. Debugger more overhead then being a good solution.
So how do i solve this issue

Try the deprecated document.execCommand, example.
